# Spotify API - Client Credentials Flow in Kotlin with Retrofit doesnt work

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, spotify

I am trying to use Spotify API. To use the API i need to get a new auth token. So per their guides [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/), I wrote the code below to request for a new token:

[image]

this is my API interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/token")
    fun getToken(@Header("Authorization") auth:String,
                 @Header("Content-Type") content :String,
                 @Field(("grant_type")) grantType:String ): Call<Token>
```

this is my MainActivity:

```
val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(TOKEN_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
        val service :TopTrackApi = retrofit.create(TopTrackApi::class.java)

        val base64String = "Basic " +  get64BaseString("6bcfc9a9fccd45c8b9bb9c980f03e653:96c65e1824084adfb1ae99ef97734621")

        Log.i("64Base ", base64String)
        val listCall : Call<Token> = service.getToken(base64String,"application/x-www-form-urlencode","client_credentials")

        listCall.enqueue(object : Callback<Token>{
            override fun onResponse(response: Response<Token>?, retrofit: Retrofit?) {
                if (response?.body() != null) {
                Log.i("Response!", response.body().access_token)
                }
                if(response?.body() == null){
                    Log.i("Response!", "null response body")
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(t: Throwable?) {
                Log.e("Error", t!!.message.toString())
            }
        })

fun get64BaseString(value:String):String{
        return Base64.encodeToString(value.toByteArray(),Base64.NO_WRAP)
    }
```

This is the token class as per their json object:
[image]

```
data class Token(
    val access_token: String,
    val expires_in: Int,
    val token_type: String
)
```

As a result I get this in Logcat:

```
I/Response: null response body
```

edit:When i am running the same values in a curl command it works(it returns the json object)

What am I doing incorrect? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it works. Else I will reproduce and update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your API interface should look like this:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@POST("api/token")
    fun getToken(@Header("Authorization") auth:String,
                 @Field(("grant_type")) grantType:String ): Call<Token>
```

Comment: it worked!! thank you so much. it's been a day I've been working on this. but you have to edit you answer. `@Header("Content-Type") content :String,` you already added this as header above.

Comment: but can you explain why did it work? What's the difference between putting the header above and as a parameter in the function?

Comment: Both should work but as the header type is not dynamic here it's better to add '@Header' above. In your case, it wasn't working because I think you have a typo in MainActivity where you are calling `service.getToken(base64String,"application/x-www-form-urlencode","client_credentials")` with second parameter as `application/x-www-form-urlencode` there should be a 'd' at the end. It should be 'encoded' not 'encode'.

Comment: yes, i just checked the old code. i forgot to add "d". thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
val base64String = "Basic "+ get64BaseString("6bcfc9a9fccd45c8b9bb9c980f03e653:96c65e1824084adfb1ae99ef97734621")
```

I think you are missing basic keyword . You need to add it as prefix to base 64 endcoded client id and secret.
There are several authorization types in HTTP for Authorization Header. Since spotify uses Basic Auth, you need to specify it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i edited the code, it still doesn't work tho

Comment: Is there any error message, you are getting? What is the status code you get from api?

Comment: no, i dont get any error. only the message i logged in case the response body is null `I/Response!: null response body`

Comment: not error, tho i get bunch of warnings like this in logcat `Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (max-target-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)`

Comment: Have you tried with postman?

Comment: i am a beginner to api and stuff, so i only know retrofit a bit.

Comment: i was able to GET data from this spotify API, but posting doesn't work so far.